# Array.map() Not rendering data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Array Like this.
[image]

I need to render this data one by one with my component . So I tried to create a map function and render this data true the map. But It's not working. I Can't find the solution for that. I am struggling with this error with like hours. I really need your help.

This is the component that I need to render my data one by one.

```
function addVariantSection(data) {
    return(
      <Grid container spacing={10}>
        <Grid item xs={12} style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between', display: 'flex' }}>
          <div>{data.variant1}</div>
          <Checkbox color='primary' inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

    )
  }
```

This is how I pass the data to this component,

```
{itemVariant.map((item)=>addVariantSection(item))}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct at glance. You only miss the `key` which is required when you render array data. E.g. `<Grid key={data._id} container spacing={10}>`

Comment: can you show how you set the array state?

Comment: How is `itemVariant` set?

Comment: @Dan
 const [itemVariant, setItemVariant] = React.useState([]); 
values.filter((configData) => configData.hasVariants && setItemVariant([configData.variants]));

Comment: If you add `useEffect(() => { console.log(itemVariant) }, [itemVariant]);` do you see your data being logged?

Comment: @Dan
Yess.I can See

Comment: Add console.log(data) statement as the first line in method addVariantSection. Do you see any data?

Comment: what about trying this

values.filter((configData) => configData.hasVariants && setItemVariant(itemVariant => ([...itemVariant, ...configData.variants]));

I'm afraid your approach would introduce more problems, you may need to normalize your data first before you set the state, try to use reduce method.